# Is Jscript.dll unique to the computer?

Tags: windows-registry

Is the `Jscript.dll` file unique to the computer?

I plan on copying the `Jscript.dll` from one of my other computers (with the same operating system) to my current computer because the one on my current computer has been merged identically by a `.reg` file.

So is it possible to copy and paste it on to a flash drive, transfer the file to my current computer, then run `Regsvr32 "C:\Windows\System32\jscript.dll"`  on the command prompt? 
After that, reboot.

Comment: Personally, I'd find the proper installer.  It sounds like your proposition won't be harmful, given it's the same OS, but you may require more than just one dll and registry settings.

Comment: I know that jscript.dll is the only file because the only error message I've been receiving is for that one file.

Comment: And what's an installer? (/newb at this)

Comment: That error message indicated Jscrict.dll is the *first* file that is missing.  It may be the only one, but there's nothing to say that JScript.dll doesn't require other missing files.  I just had a look and JScript.dll requires 41 other files and up to 214 files depending on what it's used for.  I doubt you'll do any harm with what you suggested, so long as you don't replace anything.  Give it a shot and see if it works.

Comment: I downloaded a .reg fixer from http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/230/1/Error-There-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-when-running-js-files.html . I read somewhere that the Vista version would work for Windows 7 as well. It didn't since it gave me a new error (first error was a 'There is no script engine' error. Now it's a 800a1391 error. What do you mean by JScript.dll requires 41 other files? Do I have to replace those as well?

Comment: An installer is a program that installs software on your computer.  When you put a CD in the drive, it runs the installer on the CD which copies files and configures settings on your computer.  I'm not sure which installer gives you JScript.dll.  It's a Microsoft program so I'm surprised it wasn't installed with *Windows*.  I'll take a guess it's part of *Internet Explorer*, available here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/internet-explorer/downloads/ie

Comment: And is it certain that JScript.dll will 100% need 41 other files? What did you look up?

Comment: So I'll have to re-download Internet Explorer? Also, I didn't buy the Windows 7 OS CD. I had it pre-installed when I bought my computer.

Comment: JScript needs other files, but I couldn't tell if if they're missing or not without sitting down at your computer.  An easier way may be to put the original Windows CD in the drive and ask it to repair Windows.

Comment: Can I see myself if they're missing or not? And I don't have the CD. Is there any other option (that's easy)? Also, would my original plan of replacing the JScript.dll file by copying it from another computer that runs the same OS and replacing it?

Comment: Like I said before, your original plan should be fine.

Comment: Oh, um, if I remember when I downloaded and installed IE9, there was a message about my system not compatible or something of the sorts and I foolishly dismissed it. Could I uninstall IE9 and re-install it to replace JScript.dll?

Comment: That's worth trying, but perhaps you should replace it with IE8 instead, just to ensure compatibility.  You can try to upgrade to IE9 later.

Comment: How do I replace it with IE8? I can't find the download.

Comment: Not for Windows 7 at least.

Comment: Okay, I found it and reverted back to IE8. It didn't work. And then I tried to replace the file (JScript.dll) and it wouldn't let me. It said "You need permission to perform this action".

Comment: **Do not post personal contact information in comments!** If a problem requires extended discussion to solve, please use the site's built-in [chat] functionality. @Hand-E-Food you have enough reputation to create chat rooms; if you make a new chat room and then add Amy to the write access list, you can discuss this in chat. This keeps the discussion of the problem archived on the site and publicly visible, helping future visitors. Once you have figured out the problem, post an answer below. If you have questions let me know in these comments and we can discuss in the ask a moderator chat room.

Comment: @nhinkle, thanks for that.  I wasn't aware of the chat functionality.  Also, Amy's reputation is too low to use chat.  How else can I contact an individual?

Comment: @Hand-E-Food hm... getting a user into chat who has <20 rep can be challenging, but I'm pretty sure it can be done. I think she would have to create a chat account (by clicking the chat link or going directly to http://chat.superuser.com), then you could manually add her to the room's access list if you were the owner of the room. Usually extended discussions like this automatically generate a chat room, but because Amy is a new user with <20 rep it may not do so automatically.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food if you have further questions, you can pop into the [ask a moderator chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator).